# DocumentBuilderFactory and operator

Tags: java

I am trying to parse the input 'text' line, and for some reason it gets rid of &quot. It seems all & is being ignored. How do I get this part?

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
String input = "<status> <id>000000014</id> <created_at>2012/03/07</created_at><text>&quot;Resolutionary&quot; ...</text> <retweet_count>2</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user> </status> ";
 Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
    input)));
 String value = document.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0)
    .getTextContent();
  System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Your "id" element doesn't *have* any quotes. If you find the `text` element instead of the `id` element, you'll see the double-quotes just fine.

Answer (score 2):

when you print out

```
<text>&quot;Resolutionary&quot; ...</text>
```

will become 
    "Resolutionary" ...